# Encrypted Cookies in Slim Framework v3

Tags: php, cookies, slim, slim-3, psr-7

I am writing and application in Slim Framework v3.1. I am a lot confused on how to correctly set and get the cookies using Slim's methods.

I need your help in understanding what is the right way to read and write cookies with encryption enabled.

I also need to know how to enable encryption and decryption for the same.

Currently my $app is initialised this way -

```
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../src/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);
```

My `settings.php` looks like below -

```
return [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true, // set to false in production
        'addContentLengthHeader' => false, // Allow the web server to send the content-length header

        // Renderer settings
        'renderer' => [
            'template_path' => __DIR__ . '/../templates/',
        ],
       // Cookies Encryption
        'cookies.encrypt' => true,
        'cookies.secret_key' => '53cr3t',
        'cookies.cipher' => OPENSSL_CIPHER_AES_256_CBC,
        'cookies.cipher_mode' => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Are you using any third party packages for this? If so, please mention the package as well.

Comment: @Nima I am not using any third party package for this. I have followed the instructions from slim framework v2 documentation. But, seems like, with slim v3 the standards changed due to PSR-7.

Comment: Yes Slim framework 2 has changed a lot. It does not provide any session or cookie handling out of the box, that's why I asked my first question. You should consider reading new documentation.

Comment: I have started with FigCookies as well. But, seems like there is no documentation for encryption and decryption part of FigCookies.